# Assign xml to c# struct

Tags: c#, xml

Is that possible to assgin xml file to struct?

I have xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Questions> 
 <Question id="1">
     <QuestionText>Question 1?</QuestionText>
       <Ans1>Answer</Ans1>
       <Ans2>Answer</Ans2>
       <Ans3>Answer</Ans3>
       <Ans4>Answer</Ans4>
       <CorrectAnswer>2</CorrectAnswer>
     </Question>
  <Question id="2">
    <QuestionText>Question 2?</QuestionText>
      <Ans1>Answer</Ans1>
      <Ans2>Answer</Ans2>
      <Ans3>Answer</Ans3>
      <Ans4>Answer</Ans4>
    <CorrectAnswer>1</CorrectAnswer>
  </Question>
</Questions>
```

And c# code

```
public struct Question
    {
        public string questionText;
        public string[] answers;
        public int correctAnswerIndex;
        public Question(string questionText, string[] answers, int correctAnswerIndex)
        {
            this.questionText = questionText;
            this.answers = answers;
            this.correctAnswerIndex = correctAnswerIndex;
        }
    }
```

I would like to create new question foreach xml Question with id, and assign 
QuestionText from xml to my questionText from struct , struct answers = Ans1,2,3,4 , and correctAnswerIndex would be Correct Answer from xml.
I would be grateful for every advice.

Comment: You should read a tutorial about `Serialization`

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You could use the XML Schema Definition tool ([Xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)) to auto generate the C# class from your XML file and use Deserialization to read the data from XML directly into the C# object

Steps:

- generate xsd schema file from your xml file by using the Xsd.exe

  ```
  xsd Questions.xml /outputdir:C:\myDir
  ```

This will generate Questions.xsd under the directory C:\myDir

- generate c# class from the generated xsd file by using the same Xsd.exe

  ```
  xsd Questions.xsd /classes /outputdir:C:\myDir
  ```

This will generate Questions.cs under the directory C:\myDir

- use Deserialization to read from XML into C# object

  ```
  string XmlPath = @"C:\myDir\Questions.xml";
  YourQuestionClass qObj = null;
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourQuestionClass));
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(XmlPath);
  qObj = (QuestionClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
  reader.Close();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Comment: For future readers: you can also include XSD file on your VS project without create the needed class. It will be included in your project. The difference is that in this way you can modify your schema using the XSD (with a GUI) without recreate all from scratch each time, the class will be modified automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, System.Xml.Serialization is your friend. But it work best if your class have the same structure as your XML.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Question
{
    [XmlElement("QuestionText")]
    public string QuestionText {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Answer")]
    public string[] Answer {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("CorrectAnswer")]
    public string CorrectAnswer {get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot("Questions")
public class Questions
{
    [XmlElement("Question")]
    public Question[] Question {get;set;}
}
```

Or if you are always going to have 4 possibles answer you can like this too

```
public class Question
{
    [XmlElement("QuestionText")]
    public string QuestionText {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Ans1")]
    public string Answer1 {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Ans2")]
    public string Answer2 {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Ans3")]
    public string Answer3 {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Ans4")]
    public string Answer4 {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("CorrectAnswer")]
    public string CorrectAnswer {get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot("Questions")
public class Questions
{
    [XmlElement("Question")]
    public Question[] Question {get;set;}
}
```

And the Deserialize is rather easy after

```
Questions questions = null;
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Questions));
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(yourPathToFile);

string xmlString = xmlXrds.OuterXml.ToString();
byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms))
{
   questions= (Questions)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Or you can get it in stream right away

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(yourXmlPath);
questions = (Questions)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Hope it help